# Is there a SetClip method for XOR, without excluding AND?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use the `SetClip` method, so that when a clipping region enters another one, or is partially inside the clipping region, then it will show the `GraphicsPath`. `CombineMode.Xor` is really close to what I need, however it excludes the `GraphicsPath` when it's completely inside the other clipping region. Is there a way to get a `CombineMode` like this?

The CombineMode's truth table that I need:

T T T

T F T

F T T

F F F

I've been looking for a `CombineMode` like this, but I can't find one that works the way I want it to, that being that it is excluded except from a clipping region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CombineMode Enum Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.combinemode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#fields):

**CombineMode.Union**: Two clipping regions are combined by taking the union of both.

Based on the truth table you provided, this is what you need.